# The sequence of algebraic numbers $C_n$ in $\int_0^{2 \pi} \ln(\sin(x)^{2n+1} + C_n) dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, definite-integrals, recursion, sequence-of-function

Consider the following integrals

$\int_0^{2 \pi} \ln(\sin(x)^{2n+1} + C_n) = 0$

All of the $C_n$ are algebraic numbers.

In fact all these $C_n$ can be given as zero's of some integer polynomial with degree $v$ where $0<v<2n+2$.

Conjecture 1 : All these $C_n$ are algebraic numbers of degree exactly $2n+1$.

I know how to compute these $C_n$ yet I do not immediately see how to prove conjecture 1.

Also I do not see the pattern in the polynomials that define $C_n$.

This obviously probably relates to all the ways we can solve those integrals.

$$C_0 = \frac{5}{4}$$

( see the related [Why is $\sup f_- (n) \inf f_+ (m) = \frac{5}{4} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075374/why-is-sup-f-n-inf-f-m-frac54) )

$$C_1 = 1.1792756...$$

where $C_1$ is the solution to

$$1/3 * \sqrt{x^2 - 1}(x^2 + 2) - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} = 0 $$

or

$$ 17+11*x+3*x^2+5*x^3 = 0 $$

I assume a simple recursion for these polynomials of degree $2n+1$ exists.

They are not the chebyshev polynomials though.

I am aware there are some connections to the gamma function and hypergeo functions.

One way to solve the integral is kinda like this :

1. differentiation under the integral sign.
2. substitution y = sin(x)

And then you end up with something like

$$A_m = \int (x^m + y)(1 - x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx $$

for odd integer $m$.

For instance the case $C_1$ is related to

$$A_3 = (-(\sqrt{1 - x^2} (2 + x^2)))/3 + y \arcsin[x]$$

From where we get

$$1/3 * \sqrt{x^2 - 1}(x^2 + 2) - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} = 0 $$

or

$$ 17+11*x+3*x^2+5*x^3 = 0 $$

Example for $C_0$

$$I(u) = \int_0^{2 \pi} \ln (u + \sin x) dx =  \pi \ln(u+\sqrt(u²-1)) + c$$

by using differentiation under the integral sign and then integrating.

Computing $c$ by letting $u$ go to infinity and using $u(\sin(x)/u + C_0/u)$

$I(u) = \int \ln (u + \sin x) dx$

$= \int \ln (u (1 + (\sin x)/u)) dx$

$= \int \ln u + \ln (1 + (\sin x)/u) dx$

$= \pi \ln u + \int \ln (1 + (\sin x)/u) dx)$

As $u-> \infty$,

$(\sin x)/u -> 0$

=> $1 + (\sin x)/u -> 1$

=> $\ln (1 + (\sin x)/u) -> 0$

convergence being uniform in all cases, thus the integral approaches 0. Thus, putting equations the above together, as $u-> \infty$

$\pi \ln u -> \pi \ln(u+\sqrt(u²-1)) + c$

$=> c = \lim_{u \to \infty} [\pi \ln u - \pi \ln(u+\sqrt(u²-1))]$
$= \pi \lim_{u \to\infty} [\ln u - \ln(u+\sqrt(u²-1))]$
$= \pi \lim_{u \to \infty} [\ln u - \ln(u+\sqrt(u²))]$
$= \pi \lim_{u \to \infty} [\ln u - \ln(2 u)]$
$= -\pi \ln 2.$

Therefore

$$I(u) = \pi \ln(u+\sqrt{u²-1}) - \pi \ln 2$$

giving $u = 5/4$.

And similar for the other $C_n$.

This is just one way of looking at it ofcourse.